# Video carousel with carouFredSel

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, carousel, caroufredsel

The video don't stop to play when prev button is clicked. It only works with next button.

The html code:

```
<div id="arrow-up">&laquo;</div> 
<ul id="list">          
   <li><iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/DylcJqqYKLU?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
   <li><iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/r1MN4pR5wXM?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
   <li><iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/PVzljDmoPVs?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
</ul>                     
<div id="arrow-down">&raquo;</div>
```

The script:

```
$("#list").carouFredSel({
    direction: "up",
    auto : false,
    prev : "#arrow-up",
    next : "#arrow-down"
});
```

[And here a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Gk9s/10/)

Im doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me on this page: 
http://ethosfactory.com/Branding/Projects/Videos.shtml

This is the code I used before the body close tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gallery').nivoGallery({
        startPaused: true,
        beforeChange: function(index, slide, paused){
            $('#gallery video').get(index).pause();
            },
    });
    });
</script>
```

One issue: The loading of the last slide breaks the script so that none of the Nivo nav works.